# Find an example of its sequence

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$
$\newcommand{\coloneqq}{:=}$

It is my $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ sor a field $\F$:

$$\limsup(\liminf)x_{n} \coloneqq \inf\{x \in \F : x_{n} \leq (\geq) x \text{ for almost all $x_{n}$ }\}$$

Find a sequence $(a_{n})_{n \in \N}$ such that:

$$\inf\left(\{ a_{n} \,:\, n \in \N\}\right) < \liminf\left(\{ a_{n} \,:\, n \in \N\}\right) < \limsup\left(\{ a_{n} \,:\, n \in \N\}\right) < \sup\left(\{ a_{n} \,:\, n \in \N\}\right)$$

In its case, must the set $\{ a_{n} \,:\, n \in \N\}$ have a maximum?

I think is true but I do not whatr can I do...

Suppse by contraction it do not have a maximum. Call $S =\sup\{a_{n} : n \in \N\}$So $a_{n}$. By definition for any $n \in \N$ $a_{n} \leq S$

Answer (score 2):

$a_1=-2$, $a_2=2$ and $a_n=(-1)^n$ for $n \ge 3$.

Regarding your second question. Denote $L=\limsup_n \{a_n\} \lt \sup_n \{a_n\}=S$. $L \lt S$ implies that it exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \le \frac{L+S}{2}$ for $n \ge N$. Therefore

$$\sup \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} = \sup \{a_n \mid n \lt N\}$$ and the $\sup$ of a finite set is attained.

Comment: Thats gorgeous! What do you think about the maximum I think is true!

Comment: For sure this is true. See answer update.